# Laravel queue with Amazon SQS set up message

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I am using Laravel to push messages in a Amazon SQS queue.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\ImageProcessor;
use Log;


class ImageProcessorController extends Controller
{

  public function processImage(Request $request){


    Log::info($request->all());
    Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Begins");
    dispatch(new ImageProcessor());
    Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Ends");
    echo 'image sent to the queue';

  }


}
```

and the result of this is a message in the queue like this:

```
   {
"Messages": [
    {
        "Body": "{\"displayName\":\"App\\\\Jobs\\\\ImageProcessor\",\"job\":\"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call\",\"maxTries\":null,\"timeout\":null,\"timeoutAt\":null,\"data\":{\"commandName\":\"App\\\\Jobs\\\\ImageProcessor\",\"command\":\"O:23:\\\"App\\\\Jobs\\\\ImageProcessor\\\":7:{s:6:\\\"\\u0000*\\u0000job\\\";N;s:10:\\\"connection\\\";N;s:5:\\\"queue\\\";N;s:15:\\\"chainConnection\\\";N;s:10:\\\"chainQueue\\\";N;s:5:\\\"delay\\\";N;s:7:\\\"chained\\\";a:0:{}}\"}}", 
        "Attributes": {
            "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523631711067", 
            "SenderId": "AIDAJYZES3ADLCLSKMIP2", 
            "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1", 
            "SentTimestamp": "1523631706715"
        }, 
        "ReceiptHandle": "AQEBJFyXHZdHrHLYPSK5Im2+vdXbyrrixqRbAcDVGAGzbs8re6cHIpoz57nW2g2UY+CfkcDsK66rG+qFh4O0vfmAqcc2YCWExZ+J4ixuIKoseTSmCA9ZKHxLOzRDySkDliC4Nvp6G32qh8om3oGTp3eNLMx+ooGuUTfrWipzdM6SesI04Z5fq9P8CWkCKy+Xe7146Y1eJkD68HGrj8yGxlinT5Ian57qQY2GVdXIbZFsTGz6vqB/3WVOvAGmy+b/xMsFD0SNchZUJnFVW7aCmrqKimtXAkuSbDQIhpHGMr2w1iscWtFY5JCvhiPaapkjKcAxf0luR3ygHppt/cBtTr13BNUPMXCohyGc3hdB1/XXcAF0uww+fYvWVQ8IIsYrV5lT2gpYPzg8j+7Zy7Iv1GBlGuZl6lC213AI5w93I+GEmQc=", 
        "MD5OfBody": "3a84984ce57b8d58162017adc4c2b004", 
        "MessageId": "61e4dfba-6794-48f3-a006-9637c6913553"
    }
]
}
```

as you can see the messages and attributes are set up automagically by laravel. 
The question is: how can I modify the messages?

Comment: What are you trying to modify exactly? Your ImageProcesser will be serialised and passed through so you can define anything in there per job.

Comment: I would like to add other key/values in the "Messages" array. Is there any method?

Comment: @Jamesking56 . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->dispatch(new ImageProcessor($param1, $param2, ['additional_data' => 'here']));
```

If you need more data to be sent to the queue handler (ImageProcessor in this case), just add it as parameters. It's going to get automagically, as you say, get serialized, sent and deserialized. If i'm not mistaken, it should even retrieve exact eloquent models at the other end if you pass them.

However, you can't really change the structure of the submitted message, outside of passing along additional data. Question for you is, **why would you even want to**?

If you want to send multiple messages in one go, you're gonna have write your own logic for that. Same if you want to consume the queue messages with any other platform other than Laravel.

Comment: I have added param variable to ImageProcessor call but I can't see them in teh message

Comment: 1) Is the variable you are passing set and not null? 2) Are you receiving the parameter at the other end, when you start the queue listener? 3) Why are you concerned so much about what's in the message itself? Why did you want to modify it in the first place?

Comment: I am concerned about message content because I wanted to put in the message the information that the handler need when it is its time to work. But maybe I am understanding that the handler get this data not from the message itself

Comment: Queue system in Laravel is built in such a way that you do not have to - the framework creates a message in a way that it needs to in order to do the job, and you don't have to worry (for the most part) about the SQS message content. If you are passing additional parameters to your job, but are not receiving them at the other end then try restarting your queue with `php artisan queue:restart` and if it's still not working then update your answer and post your new code that's not working.